# Java - Help needed with file reading and delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a file with the contents :

- 85,70,95,82,75
- 70,78,85,62,47,53,32
- 99,88,75,85,69,72
- 79,84,86,91,84,89,78,82,70,75,82
- 56,68,0,56
- 96,82,91,90,88

I need to write a code using the java Scanner class to read and output the code in this order :

- 85,70,95,82,75
- 85 70 95 82 75
- 70,78,85,62,47,53,32
- 70 78 85 62 47 53 32
- 99,88,75,85,69,72
- 99 88 75 85 69 72
  etc...

However, I cannot seem to get my code to work for the life of me and I can't figure out what I'm not understanding. I have gotten very close with my results but I have tried so many solution at this point I just gave up. This is the current code I have. Which is almost the best result I've gotten.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FileIO
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        File fileObj2 = new File("Scores.txt");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(fileObj2);
        String line = "";
        String x = "";      

        Scanner scan3 = null;
        scan3 = new Scanner(fileObj2);  
        scan3.useDelimiter(",");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Second Files data below \n ------------- 
        ---------");
        while (scan2.hasNextLine()){
            line = scan2.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            while (scan3.hasNext()){
                line2 = scan3.next();
                System.out.print(line2 + " " );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which give me the output

```
85,70,95,82,75
85 70 95 82 75
70 78 85 62 47 53 32
99 88 75 85 69 72
79 84 86 91 84 89 78 82 70 75 82
56 68 0 56
96 82 91 90 88 70,78,85,62,47,53,32
99,88,75,85,69,72
79,84,86,91,84,89,78,82,70,75,82
56,68,0,56
96,82,91,90,88
```

Comment: you just want to read and print each line twice ?

Comment: Simply read each line, call `.replace(",", "");` and print it twice.

Comment: well print it once, then print the .replace(","," "). Note there is a space between the second set of quotes.

Comment: I want it to read each line, print the original and print the version that is not in CSV format. However, I am not just trying to produce the result but make it by using the Scanner and useDelimiter method. I am fully aware of the String replace() method but that is not the method I am wanting to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` method to get the required results. See below snippet for your reference.

```
String line = "87,88,89,90,91";
System.out.println(line);
System.out.println(line.replace(',',' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

small changes in code, please find them below,

```
            while (scan2.hasNextLine()){
            line = scan2.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            scan3 = new Scanner(line);
            scan3.useDelimiter(","); 
            while (scan3.hasNext()){
                System.out.print(scan3.next());
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is an approach I have came to before, however while using this approach when the second loop is ran it prints the line , but does not remove the ",", almost as if the delimiter is not being used which is what I cant figure out why or how to fix this error.

Comment: you can refer the link for a sample code on how useDelimiter works https://code.hackerearth.com/adb21fT

Comment: I tried the solution you edited. However, I still had the same problem. The format is definitely what I was looking for but the commas were still showing in the second output from the second loop. The only way I've gotten the delimiter to actually work is by the code that I updated above. If maybe you are able to fix it so that they output one after the other (like the example provided) that'd be great. I've been trying to find this solution for 2 days now.

Comment: oh god how did I miss this, here's it we are assigning a new Scanner every time we need to assign a delimiter again after that... I did a mistake there...I am making a change again please let me know if its working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replaceAll` method to remove the commas.

Scores.txt:

```
85,70,95,82,75
70,78,85,62,47,53,32
99,88,75,85,69,72
79,84,86,91,84,89,78,82,70,75,82
56,68,0,56
96,82,91,90,88
```

Code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Scores.txt"));
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String out = line.replaceAll(","," ");
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println(out);
}
```

Output:

```
70,78,85,62,47,53,32
70 78 85 62 47 53 32
99,88,75,85,69,72
99 88 75 85 69 72
79,84,86,91,84,89,78,82,70,75,82
79 84 86 91 84 89 78 82 70 75 82
56,68,0,56
56 68 0 56
96,82,91,90,88
96 82 91 90 88
```